# Voting between classifiers with different training data samples

Tags: python, classification, voting

I have a dataset with 25 features, 36000 samples, and 11 labels. In python I want to train some classifiers (with same type or not) with different samples of this dataset. In other words, the training data samples of each classifier is different from the training data samples of another model. Of course labels and features are same and the difference is about samples. Then I want to vote between trained classifiers. Existed functions of python do voting with same training data. I really appreciate if you can help me to solve the issue in python.

I have tried to use voting functions of python, but unfortunately these functions accept same training data for all base classifiers.

Comment: Do you want to do the voting on training samples or testing samples?

Comment: I want to do voting for test or validation samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the predictions by all your classifiers and append them to a list:

```
on_hot_encoded = True  # Change this to False if your models don not produce one-hot encoded predictions.
outputs = []
for i in range(n_models):
    preds = models[i].predict(x_test)
    # If the predictions are one-hot enocded, this line of the code will convert them into categorical classes
    if one_hot_encoded:
        preds /= np.max(preds , axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
    outputs.append(preds)

outputs = np.array(outputs).T
utlimate = [max(set(list(row)), key = list(row).count) for row in outputs]
```

For your example:

```
import numpy as np
y1 = [1,2,3,0,1,2,1,1,0]
y2 = [2,1,3,1,0,1,2,1,0]
y3 = [1,2,0,1,0,2,1,1,3]
y=[]
y.append(y1)
y.append(y2)
y.append(y3)
y = np.array(y).T
ultimate = [max(set(list(row)), key=list(row).count) for row in y]
print(ultimate)
```

The output:

[image: This is the output I got from the above code]

Comment: Thank you dear Reza for your answer.
As a simple example I've tried your code as below and it is obvious that in this sample the output of voting must be [1,2,3,1,0,2,1,1,0]:
Import pandas as pd
Import numpy as np
y1 = [1,2,3,0,1,2,1,1,0]
y2 = [2,1,3,1,0,1,2,1,0]
y3 = [1,2,0,1,0,2,1,1,3]
y=[]
y.append(y1)
y.append(y2)
y.append(y3)
y = np.array(y).T
for row in y:
    key = list(row).count
    utlimate = [max(set(list(row))]             The code does not return the value with most repitition. Maybe I've made a mistake but I've tried also exactly your code and that does not work.

Comment: But this code is different and it has some issues. The max() function must be applied on two values which are set(list(row)) and key=list(row).count). But in your code, it is only applied on set(list(row)). Also, you find the maximum value, not the most prevalent one. And also, each time, you do the operations only on one row. Please use exactly my code. I tested it and it worked seamlessly.

Comment: I edited the answer and included your example with its result.

Comment: Thank you dear Reza for your perfect and kind answer. After voting I want to plot confusion matrix for the classifier using confusion matrix from sklearn. In normal conditions it works well but when I use voting according to your hint, I receive an error: "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples" in the confusion matrix stage. Maybe the error is occurred due to changes created in the voting procedure. I would be grateful if you can help me to solve this issue and complete my code's final step

Comment: You are welcome. If you share the shape of your actual and predicted outputs, I can check it.